# Error "The byte array is not a recognized imageformat" reading image of type byte[] from database for itextSharp in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, itext

I hope you can help me. I explain the following:
I get the photo from the database, which is saved as a byte array:

```
List<DevolImgModels> list_img = new List<DevolImgModels>();
string sql = "SELECT img.foto FROM contratostimg img";
conexion.conection(constring);

using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexion.con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    using (MySqlDataReader d = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (d.Read())
        {
            list_img.Add(new DevolImgModels
            {
                foto = (byte[])d["foto"] //I put the photo in a list_img list, and photo is of type byte[]
            });
         }
    }
}

conexion.close();

Image foto = Image.GetInstance(fila.foto);
PdfPCell c = new PdfPCell(foto, true);
c.Image.ScaleToFitHeight = false; 
table.AddCell(c);  

//...
//code definitions to create the pdf. I put the dots to save code and go straight to the problem

foreach (var fila in list_img)
{
    //...
       
    Image foto = Image.GetInstance(fila.foto);
    PdfPCell c = new PdfPCell(foto, true);
    c.Image.ScaleToFitHeight = false; 
    table.AddCell(c);     
}
```

But when passing row.photo(of type byte[]) to Image, it gives an error, that is, in this line of code it gives the error:

```
Image foto = Image.GetInstance(fila.foto);
```

And the error it gives is the following:

**The byte array is not a recognized imageformat**

buggy image:
[this is the test image](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am062GDJ5L_xgcw2M7f02zMVeVmjRA?e=xxxLPk)

I wish I could fix it, if anyone has any ideas or solutions I would appreciate it.

Best regards.

Comment: Apparently that photo is in a format ItextSharp doesn't know. Have you checked whether all your photos are rejected or just some? Have you stored the bytes of a rejected photo and checked the file?

Comment: @mkl happens with some photos. In this case the photos that come out with an error, I can download them and they look correct.

Comment: What format are the photos that work in? What format are the photos that don't work, in? You may need to look at them with a hex editor. I don't use iText anymore but it used to be a real PITA.

Comment: Can you share one of those rejected photos?

Comment: Watch it be a webp/hevc image lol

Comment: I uploaded the link of the image in the question
https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ADO39NszFXlZo0Q&cid=F1BFE4C960D83A6D&id=F1BFE4C960D83A6D%2126166&parId=F1BFE4C960D83A6D%2120134&o=OneUp

Comment: maybe you have to do some kind of purer JPG conversion of the image before saving it.

Comment: I checked the file with some JPG validators and they report issues. Apparently not too bad issues because some image viewers display a proper image while others don't. Apparently iTextSharp does not ignore those issues.